# How would I get my toast action button to work with an assigned action?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I'm trying to create a toast notification with an action button attached to the message. How can I get the button to work when clicked in the UI?

I'd like the action event to do different things with other use cases, so keeping this modifiable is preferred.

```
export const ToastAction = {
    init() {
      this.hideTimeout = null;
  
      this.el = document.createElement("div");
      this.el.className = "toastAction";
      document.body.appendChild(this.el);
    },
  
    show(message, action, state) {
      clearTimeout(this.hideTimeout);
  
      this.el.className = "toastAction toast--visible";

      const text = document.createElement("p");
      text.textContent = message;
      this.el.appendChild(text);

      const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = action;
      this.el.appendChild(button);
  
      if (state) {
        this.el.classList.add(`toast--${state}`);
      }
  
    //   this.hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    //     this.el.classList.remove("toast--visible");
    //   }, 5000);                  
    }
  };
  
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => ToastAction.init());
```

```
// show toast message and button + add click event to button

    ToastAction.show("message", "Text", "success").onclick(alert("clicked!"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, I understand the problem right

```
  ..................
      if (state) {
        this.el.classList.add(`toast--${state}`);
      }
  
    //   this.hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    //     this.el.classList.remove("toast--visible");
    //   }, 5000);  
      return button;                
    }
  };
```

```
ToastAction.show("message", "Text", "success").onclick(() => alert("clicked!"))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for taking the time. I need to learn properly what the return statement does for the future.